# Joining two tables by date when all dates don't match

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, one with dates and revenue predictions and another table with dates and revenue predictions. I would like to join the tables together on the dates however, when i do that the join deletes the records that don't match. I would like to keep the records that don't match.
Here's an example of the table. I'm okay with there being duplications.

Table A

```
Date         Rev
01-01-2021   30,000
01-02-2021   26,000
01-03-2021   28,000
```

Table B

```
Date         Rev
01-01-2021   30,000
01-02-2021   26,000
01-03-2021   28,000
03-05-2021   31,000
```

Comment: I guess you `INNER JOIN` when you need a `LEFT JOIN`. But you haven't shown any code

Comment: Do you really want to join rows or do you rather want the union of the tables (with `UNION [DISTINCT]` or `UNION ALL`)?

Comment: Please tag your request with the DBMS you are using. With SQL request we usually need to know the DBMS, because SQL dialects differ and a solution for one DBMS may not work for another.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FULL OUTER JOIN` to keep both sides:

```
select TA.*, TB.*
from TableA as TA
     FULL OUTER JOIN
     TableB as TB
     on TA.Date=TB.Date
```

I don't know your dbms product (SqlServer, Oracle, etc..) so I can't tell if it allows full outer join, and if Date is a reserved word.

Comment: I'm using SqlServer and i have tried left join and right join on date but it's still getting rid of the unmatched date.

Comment: Have you tried full outer join as I suggested?